# Voidwalker's nova bomb cooldown

Tags: destiny

I was playing Destiny two days ago (my char is a Warlock-Voidwalker) and the matchmaking has given me a decent team. In this team there was another Voidwalker that was SO "unusual"...
As the game was going on, I noticed that he had a nova bomb ready everytime we met an enemy. 
I started following him and discovered that I was right: he was casting nova bombs like every 30 seconds or less... 
Pretty sure about the fact that he was a cheater, I didn't bother searching through the web for a solution. 
Yesterday, while cooking, I turned on my console and decided to watch some good Destiny's action on Twitch. Entered a channel and, SURPRIIIIIISE, found a warlock with a 20/30seconds nova bomb casting time doing a raid into the Vault of Glass..... 
Now the question is pretty simple: is it just me or those two guys are both cheaters?! 
If not, does someone have an exhaustive guide on how to setup the Voidwalker class to reach this goal? Every walkthrough I've found on the web didn't gave any noticeable result...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although cheating is a possibility, they probably achieved this through proper perks and armor stats.

Firstly the armor stat [Intellect](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Intellect) decreases the cooldown of your super substantially.

Also many armors and weapons have perks on them for super generation. As an example, here is one Warlock [helmet](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Skull_of_Dire_Ahamkara) that replenishes super energy on grenade kills.

Combining perks and intellect makes it very possible to have a super on that short of a cooldown.

Next time you come across one of these players inspect them to see what they have built.

Comment: Also the final VoidWalker ability is that energy-drain is activated when you do damage with your grenades or super.  One of the energy drain effects can be set to reduce the cool down of your super.

Comment: You can take a look at [this](http://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/2jiryt/voidwalker_energy_drain_the_more_you_know_and_the/) thread on Reddit for some tips on how to build a quick-recharge VoidWalker. It touches on the perks and armor that make something like super-quick recharges possible.

Comment: It's also possible to put together armor combinations which cause ability usages to recharge each other.  For example I have a helmet which has `Grenade hits recharge melee energy` and gloves with `Melee hits replenish grenade energy` - virtuous cycle :)

Answer (score 1):

Two words, Obsidian Mind. Exotic warlock helmet that regen super whenever you kill someone with a super.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to think about before even *considering* that someone might be cheating on a closed platform is that they might be better at picking up orbs of light than you.

Anytime a member of your party other than you uses a super, they generate orbs of light on the ground (which you can see but they can't).

Picking those up shortens your super recharge time a lot.

Put together with armor and abilities that shorten it, and yeah, roughly 30 seconds should be achievable.

Comment: I'm a 25 Warlock, I know how Destiny works xD Even if you pick up all the orbs on a map you can cast your super ONE time, then you have to wait for other people to generate orbs (and that's almost impossible to be done in 20/30 seconds) or do something yourself... I have to kill 4/5 enemies (at least 2 of them with a punch) to fully recharge my super... and obviously I need at least 40 seconds (if I'm lucky). The guy twitching his game was almost like SUPERCHARGE > KILL ENEMY WITH SUPERCHARGE > KILL ANOTHER ENEMY JUST SHOOTING AT HIM > SUPERCHARGE AGAIN... it's an endless destruction loop O_O

Answer (score 0):

look at the stat list where it says "killing enemies with energy drain reduces the cool down of your next nova bomb", then look at where it says "killing enemies with any of your abilities triggers the energy drain effect", the look where it ways "Increases the duration of energy drain", then get obsidian mind and 100% intellect and in the abyss on crota's end, your can have a nova bomb once about 15 seconds.